# MySQL Server stops working on heavy calculation load

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures

When executing the attached procedure, mysql hangs up and does not replay anymore until cancelling the task. It is installed locally on a windows machine. Its whole performance is terribly. What to do?

//edit: System information: i7 3GHz, 8GB RAM, Windows 8.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fix_lft_rgt_news ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE v_char VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE maximumId INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE currentId INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE currentLft INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE categoryLft INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE categoryId INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE v_parseStr VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ' ';

    SELECT MIN(id) INTO i FROM avsn_assets WHERE name LIKE 'com_content.article%';
    SELECT id INTO categoryId FROM avsn_assets WHERE title = 'News' AND name LIKE 'com_content.category%';
    SELECT lft INTO categoryLft FROM avsn_assets WHERE title = 'News' AND name LIKE 'com_content.category%';
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO maximumId FROM avsn_assets WHERE name LIKE 'com_content.article%';
    SET currentLft = categoryId + 1;

    WHILE (i <= maximumId )  DO 

        UPDATE `avsn_assets` SET `lft` = currentLft WHERE `id` = i;
        UPDATE `avsn_assets` SET `rgt` = currentLft + 1 WHERE `id` = i;

        SET currentLft = currentLft + 2;

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    UPDATE `avsn_assets` SET `rgt` = currentLft + 1 WHERE `id` = cateGoryId;    
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the problem....It is the hard disk slowing down the server.